# Google Login with Firebase Auth returning an error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, sha1, google-signin

I opted to go with Firebase Auth for my app and it's generally pretty straightforward. I changed Google accounts early in the development because I wanted to keep these two separate, and I suspect that's what's causing my errors here.

When I click the Google login button, it pulls up the account chooser and then returns nothing. Here's the error in the logs:

`GoogleProvider: Error logging in with Google. 10 null`

From the Firebase issue tracker, it seems to be associated with a change in your SHA1 fingerprint. Here's the rub: my initial Firebase account has no SHA1 fingerprints associated with it.

Things I've done:

- Verified that I have the right SHA token in there, I even brought in the debug ones and I can't seem to get it logged in.
- Copied the google-services.json from the correct account.
- Tested Twitter, Facebook, and Email and they work flawlessly.

Anyone have any experience here?

Comment: Just for kicks I did it all again: Retrieved both Release and Debug SHA1 and SHA256 tokens, made sure there weren't any on any other projects (even semi related), replaced existing ones in current project, copied the google-services.json file into my project, ran it, and got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I was able to find the answer in [this Firebase issue tracker thread](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/498).

> this issue is occuring on debugs builds, right? Every android studio
>   installation creates a different debug key so you'll have to
>   regenerate it.

I have two machines that I work on. One is my desktop that I've been pulling keys from (because that's where my release key resides), and another is my laptop where I can code off the cuff. **If I want to use the debug build to test this, I need to use the debug SHA1 from the actual machine that I'm running.**